# Is there a command line interface to the Drobo tools in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, drobo

Before powering down the Drobo and removing it you're supposed to use the "shutdown" functionality from the Drobo Dashboard.  Is there a way to call this from the command line so it can be included in a script?